# PMD: the chosen operation is not currently available

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, pmd

I had installed PMD in my local system, I use to run PMD. But, recently I have observed that when I right on project/package in STS->pmd->check code with PMD, then getting following error:

```
the chosen operation is not currently available.
```

Java: 1.6.0_30

PMD: 4.0.0.2

Answer (score 2):

Just Restart your eclipse. Some time it happen if you not properly shutdown eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

"The chosen operation is not currently available" usually means that the class that implements your action cannot be loaded. Re-installing the PMD should solve the problem.